# How to wrap text in button to multiple lines?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

In telegram bot based on `telegraf`, I want to wrap text into multiple lines. Now it shows only part of that.

[image: shows like this:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a client-side limit, unfortunately, you can't do this at this time :(

You can make a suggestion to [Telegram Supporter](https://telegram.org/faq#telegram-support).

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text into multiple lines using

```
import textwrap
InlineKeyboardButton(textwrap.fill(answer)
```